# For loop used to open multiple txt files doesn't return anything

Tags: python, pandas

The code below doesn't return anything, while I expect it to return a `pandas` dataframe. Where am I going wrong?

```
import pandas as pd
from pathlib import Path

files = Path('./finance_data').glob('*.txt')

d = {}

for file in files:
    with file.open() as f:
       contents = f.readlines()
       name = contents[4].removeprefix('Name:').removesuffix('\n')
       longitude = contents[10].removeprefix('Longitude:').removesuffix('\n')
       latitude = contents[11].removeprefix('Latitude:').removesuffix('\n')
       d['name'] = name
       d['lon'] = longitude
       d['lat'] = latitude

df = pd.DataFrame([d])
print(df)
```

EDIT 1, as requested:

```
print(files)
<generator object Path.glob at 0x00000287C9B610B0>

print(d)
{'name': 'XDF', 'lon': ' 65.656991', 'lat': ' 62.013306'}
```

Comment: Can you please give an example of the content of the files?

Comment: how do you expect it to return something without a return statement?

Comment: @Dan Curry: there is no function here

Comment: @mozway it is a txt file with many lines, how should I put it on here? Thank you for your comment

Comment: @mozway very true.

Comment: Well, you can try to minimize the file by removing repeated parts, or use an external file hosting provider

Comment: Also, it's worth mentioning that you're overwriting the contents of d at every loop.

Comment: Maybe there are no text files in the folder.

Comment: @salix_august: can you give the value of `files` and `d` at the end of the code?

Comment: @mozway, sorry, what do you mean the value of files? Sorry

Comment: add `print(files) ; print(d)` at the end and give the output

Comment: @mozway I added this as edit in the post - thank you

Comment: OK, it should have been `print(list(files))` not `print(files)`, can you update? Also, I proposed an answer, let me know if it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code, I hope it should work. If not, please post the detailed traceback.

```
import pandas as pd
from pathlib import Path

files = Path('./finance_data').glob('*.txt')

d = []

for file in files:
    with file.open() as f:
       contents = f.readlines()
       name = contents[4].removeprefix('Name:').removesuffix('\n')
       longitude = contents[10].removeprefix('Longitude:').removesuffix('\n')
       latitude = contents[11].removeprefix('Latitude:').removesuffix('\n')
       d.append({'name': name, 'lon': longitude, 'lat':  latitude})

df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

Comment: You can also thank @matheubv, overwriting the variable `d` was the main error in your code ;)